# Looping through a dictionary to replace multiple values in text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to change several hex values in a text file. I made a CSV that has the original values in one column and the new values in another.

My goal is to write a simple Python script to find old values in the text file based on the first column and replace them with new values in the second.

I'm attempting to use a dictionary to facilitate this `replace()` that I created by looping through the CSV. Building it was pretty easy, but using it to executing a `replace()` hasn't been working out. When I print out the values after my script runs I'm still seeing the original ones.

I've tried reading in the text file using `read()` and executing the change to the whole file like above.

```
import csv

filename = "origin.txt"
csv_file = 'replacements.csv'
conversion_dict = {}

# Create conversion dictionary
with open(csv_file, "r") as replace:
    reader = csv.reader(replace, delimiter=',')
    for rows in reader:
        conversion_dict.update({rows[0]:rows[1]})

#Replace values on text files based on conversion dict
with open(filename, "r") as fileobject:
    txt = str(fileobject.read())
    for keys, values, in conversion_dict.items():
        new_text = txt.replace(keys, values)
```

I've also tried adding the updated text to a list:

```
#Replace values on text files based on conversion dict
with open(filename, "r") as fileobject:
    txt = str(fileobject.read())
    for keys, values, in conversion_dict.items():
        new_text.append(txt.replace(keys, values))
```

Then, I tried using `readlines()` to replace the old values with new ones one line at a time:

```
# Replace values on text files based on conversion dict
with open(filename, "r") as reader:
    reader.readlines()
    type(reader)
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
        for keys, values, in conversion_dict.items():
            new_text.append(txt.replace(keys, values))
```

While troubleshooting, I ran a test to see if I was getting any matches between the keys in my dict and the text in the file:

```
for keys, values, in conversion_dict.items():
    if keys in txt:
        print("match")
    else:
        print("no match")
```

My output returned `match` on every row except the first one. I imagine with some trimming or something I could fix that. However, this proves that there are matches, so there must be some other issue with my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you forgot to write the replaced text back to the file. `txt` is a string not your file. Also not sure what `new_text` is; seems to me that you want to use `txt` not `new_text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

origin.txt:

```
oldVal9000,oldVal1,oldVal2,oldVal3,oldVal69
```

test.csv:

```
oldVal1,newVal1
oldVal2,newVal2
oldVal3,newVal3
oldVal4,newVal4
```

```
import csv

filename = "origin.txt"
csv_file = 'test.csv'
conversion_dict = {}

with open(csv_file, "r") as replace:
    reader = csv.reader(replace, delimiter=',')
    for rows in reader:
        conversion_dict.update({rows[0]:rows[1]})

f = open(filename,'r')
txt = str(f.read())
f.close()

txt= txt.split(',')         #not sure what your origin.txt actually looks like, assuming comma seperated values
for i in range(len(txt)):
    if txt[i] in conversion_dict:
        txt[i] = conversion_dict[txt[i]]
        
with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(",".join(txt))
```

modified origin.txt:

```
oldVal9000,newVal4,newVal1,newVal3,oldVal69
```

Comment: It's delimited by new lines, so swapping out that comma out for `\n` did the trick. Thanks!